# Properties of tangent functor

Tags: differential-geometry, category-theory, tangent-spaces

When I was learning differential geometry, I was told that differential of a function can be viewed as a functor, i.e. sending manifold into tangent space and function into its differential. Unfortunately, I believe that it's simply abstract nonsense, since I cannot find any references on the properties of tangent functor, for example, when it's exact, when it keeps injective (*a bit wired, since there are piles of injection, immersed or embedded for example*), or whether it keeps the limit or colimit. (*for finite product, it's evident*)

So is there any reference for the properties of tangent functor? Thanks!

Comment: Great question! I would like to see what comes of this. None of the references I have go into detail other than stating its definition.

Comment: But how can you choose which tangent space to consider? If you you switch to the category of Lie groups you find a nice equivalence with the category of Lie Algebras

Comment: @FedericoT. Yes, for the category of Lie group, there is a nice equivalence. However, I mean for all smooth manifolds.

Comment: @Liam To define such a functor for manifolds, you need at least to consider the category of *pointed* manifolds, otherwise how can you choose which tangent space to consider? Nevertheless recall that the category of smooth manifolds is terrible as it is very far from being even (co)complete: for example pullbacks exist only if one of the maps is a summersion.

Comment: @FedericoT. Thanks very much. Yes, we need the category of $\operatorname{Man}_{*}$, the pointed manifold.